Why doesnt Grignard reagent precipitate in ether?
I read that Grignard reagents are stabilised in ether by the coordinate bond formation, but according to the Schlenk equilibrium, RMgX is in equilibrium with MgX2 and R2Mg. Here MgX2 is ionic and thus precipitate out of the ether, driving the reaction. So shouldn't the Grignard be finished?

I think you overestimate importance of Schlenk equilibrium, but it's worth analysing.
